# /PAGE_ID/tabs Application does not have permission for this action

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebookpage and an application. All is working well.
But i am getting the following exception when I try to add a tab to a page

> Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #10) (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

I am calling with this code (c# facebook sdk):

```
var client = new FacebookClient(page.AccessToken);
client.AppId = this.settings.FacebookApplicationId;
client.AppSecret = this.settings.FacebookApplicationSecret;

dynamic result = client.Post(string.Join(@"/", page.FacebookId, "tabs"), new { app_id =    fbApplication.FacebookId });
```

Comment: I have a page_access_token with manage_pages and i am admin on the page.

Comment: Could you fix it? I have the same problem

Comment: No it seems that facebook have removed those permissions.